# How can i create a relation beetwen two models and pass the model info on to the view through the controller?

Tags: eloquent, foreign-key-relationship, laravel-5.4

My Student Model

```
 /**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function fathers()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Father');
}
```

My StudentController

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param ManageStudentRequest $request
 * @param  int $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(ManageStudentRequest $request, $id)
{
    $student = Student::with('fathers')->find($id);

    return view('students.show')->withStudent($student);
}
```

And my Blade View

```
<tr>
    <th>NOMBRE</th>
    <td>{{ $student->father->first_name }} {{ $student->father->last_name }}</td>
</tr>
```

The thing is i get this mistake:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\laragon\www\App\resources\views\students\partials\show\show-overview.blade.php) (View: C:\laragon\www\App\resources\views\students\partials\show\show-overview.blade.php)
```

Im in desperate need for help, anything is useful, tyvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should setup your structure to have a many to many relationship between students and fathers if that's the logic you want, so:

```
public function fathers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Father');

    //Also define the inverse relationship on the Father model.
}
```

Now assuming you've done that then:

On this query `$student = Student::with('fathers')->find($id);` just append `first()` so it looks like this:

`$student = Student::with('fathers')->find($id)->first();`

Then in your view you can access them like this:

`<td>{{ $student->father->first_name }} {{ $student->father->last_name }}</td>`